# jQuery-JSONP plugin fails when placed in a directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I have an HTML page that uses the [JSONP Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/) to gracefully handle errors in my JSONP call. My problem is quite perplexing (and I hope it has a simple, easy "D'Oh!" solution :)).
When the .js file is in the same directory as the HTML page and is loaded like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jsonp.min.js"></script>
```

All works well. But if I move it to the internal JS directory, where all my other JS files are:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jsonp.min.js"></script>
```

It always calls the error function. I traced it with FireBug and it calls the `$.jsonp` function, but immediately jumps to the error function.
The code itself looks like this:

```
$.jsonp(
  {
    url: ipUrl, 
    timeout: 30000,
    success: displayData,
    error: displayError
  }
);
```

Any ideas? I really want to ship this in an organized manner. Thanks for your time.

Couple of facts: the page is tested **locally** (no web server). There are **no permissions/security issues**. There are other .js files in that same directory that load well. The error occurs in all browsers.

**UPDATE**: based on Alex's suggestion, I downloaded the unminified version and put it in the js directory. I changed the reference in HTML page and traced with FireBug. The function DOES receive the right URL and actually works!
 I went back and forth from unminified to minified and the result is clear: something is screwed up in the minified version!
Still, I wonder what could screw up a function in a way that its location matters??? Should I just ship the unminifed version and forget about it?

**Update 2 - the solution**: I minified the open file myself (I used Alex's link to get the [C# code for JSMin](http://crockford.com/javascript/jsmin)), I compiled, and minimized the file - and it worked. I then compared it to the file I downloaded - the carriage returns were screwed. Downloaded the file again - and everything works.

Comment: You could still minify it yourself with something like http://compressorrater.thruhere.net/ and see if you get the same bad results.

Comment: Alex: you got me to the right answer. I used your link to get the C# code for http://crockford.com/javascript/jsmin, I compiled, and minimized the file - and it worked. I then compared it to the file I downloaded - the carriage returns were screwed. Downloaded the file again - and it works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but if the ipUrl is local to the page as well (for testing), then perhaps when the script gets added from a different directory its trying to hit a local file that doesnt exist relative to its location. That would immediately throw the error function.

Can you use the non minified version of the script to debug and see what url its trying to hit?

Comment: Actually, ipUrl is defined 2 lines above the function call. I will get the unminified version and try to step in...

Comment: Damn! You wouldn't believe it. Downloaded unminified version and put it in the js directory. Changed reference in HTML page and traced with FireBug. The function DOES rceive the right URL and actually works! I went back and forth from unminified to minified and the result is clear: something is screwed up in the minified version! Still, I wonder what could screw up a function in a way that its location matters??? I'll add this info to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly setting the `callbackParameter`?

```
$.jsonp({
    url: ipUrl, 
    callbackParameter: 'nameOfTheCallbackParameterThatYourServerSideScriptExpects',
    timeout: 30000,
    success: displayData,
    error: displayError
});
```